# interpretation of singular value as stretching of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

For the matrix

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1+\epsilon
\end{array}\right)
$$

where $\epsilon\ll 1$, the singular values are approximately $2$ and $\epsilon/2$. The first is easy to understand: we take

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1+\epsilon
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}\right)\approx2\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}\right).
$$

However, for the second, we take

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1+\epsilon
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
-\epsilon
\end{array}\right).
$$

The norm of the vector on the right is $\epsilon$, while that of the vector on the left is $\sqrt{2}$, so this matrix has stretched the vector by a factor of $\epsilon / \sqrt{2}$. So why is singular value $\epsilon / 2$?

Comment: Try using a better approximation for the eigenvector instead: $\pmatrix{1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\ -1}$ instead of $\pmatrix{1\\-1}$

Comment: Indeed, to first order the eigenvectors are $\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1-\epsilon/4 \\ 1 + \epsilon/4\end{pmatrix}$ and $\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1+\epsilon/4 \\ -1 + \epsilon/4\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Got it. The key is that the eigenvalue shift happens at second order, not first. If there were a non-zero first-order shift, then the method used above would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I realized (with much thanks to the comments) that the key is to keep track of $\epsilon$ carefully up to second order. Let $A^{T}A=M_{0}+\epsilon M_{1}+\epsilon^{2}M_{2}$, where

$$
M_{0}=2\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right),\;M_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{array}\right),\;M_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right).
$$

The zeroth-order eigenvalue is $\lambda_0 = 0$ and $x_{0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1
\end{array}\right)$.

At first order, we have $M_{0}x_{1}+M_{1}x_{0}=\lambda_{1}x_{0}$, leading to $x_{0}^{T}M_{1}x_{0}=\lambda_{1}$, but from a straightforward computation, this is also zero. This is the key reason why the method in the original question gives the wrong answer. Solving $M_{0}x_{1}=-M_{1}x_{0}$, we obtain $x_{1}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}\right)$, as stated by the second comment under the original question post.

At second order, we have $M_{0}x_{2}+M_{1}x_{1}+M_{2}x_{0}=\lambda_{2}x_{0}$. Multiplying by $x^T_0$, we obtain $x_{0}^{T}M_{1}x_{1}+x_{0}^{T}M_{2}x_{0}=\lambda_{2}$. By straightforward computation, we have $\lambda_2 = 1/4$. Hence, we have $\sigma=\sqrt{\lambda_{2}\epsilon^{2}+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{3})}\approx\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.